# What is the timeout period for reCAPTCHA v2 for inactivity?

Tags: recaptcha

I have a form and that uses Google reCaptcha V2. There is a delay , which is more than a minute caused by the backend API call. While waiting for the response from server, reCAPTCHA is showing that it is expired. I thought that the expiration timing is 2 minutes, but it is explicitly specified as two minutes for V3. What is the expiration time for V2 and how can I fix this issue ?

I am using the VueJs plugin for reCaptcha. called [vue-recaptcha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha). Please find the code below:

```
<vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="onVerify" @expired="onExpired" :sitekey="recaptchaSiteKey"></vue-recaptcha>
<input name="recaptchaResponse" v-model="recaptchaResponse" v-validate="'required'" type="hidden" ></input>
```

Now the onExpired method is like the following:

```
onExpired: function () {
  this.recaptchaResponse = null
},
```

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate which framework are you using? In order for a code snippet to be formed.

Comment: Great. I was able to find information on V2 timeout timings here: https://github.com/dozoisch/react-google-recaptcha/issues/184

Comment: Try to see if the reset() function could be used in your case, as it creates a new access token.

Comment: Yeah. I think the expiry is ~50 seconds. This makes sense in my case. Anyway I will use the `reset()`  here.